# One field - different value for different record type

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have a total amount formula field ((all products * term) + one time amount) on an opportunity. Also I have 3 different record types for opportunities.
Now the sales team want this field to show for 2/3 record type the above and only for one specific record type the formula - 40 %.

I tried it with one and got a syntax error (Missing ")":

```
If((RecordType.DeveloperName = "ATS", ((Monthly_amount__c * Term__c) +  Onetime_amount__c) * 0.6),
(Monthly_amount__c * Term__c) +  Onetime_amount__c)
```

Also not sure how to put the OR for the second record type in it.
BR Alex

Comment: Your brackets are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IF` formula function takes three parameters:

1. The *expression*
2. The value when *expression* is true
3. The value when *expression* is false.

Try updating this like:

```
((Monthly_amount__c * Term__c) + Onetime_amount__c) * IF(RecordType.DeveloperName = 'ATS', 0.6, 1.0)
```

The common part of the calculation doesn't need to be duplicated, so I took it out of the `IF`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Works like a charm @phil-w